# Python, NameError in urllib2 module but only in a few websites

Tags: python, urllib2, nameerror

```
website = raw_input('website: ')
with open('words.txt', 'r+') as arquivo:
    for lendo in arquivo.readlines():
        msmwebsite = website + lendo
        try:
            abrindo = urllib2.urlopen(msmwebsite)
            abrindo2 = abrindo.read()           

        except URLError as e:
            pass

        if abrindo.code == 200:
            palavras = ['registration', 'there is no form']
            for palavras2 in palavras:
                if palavras2 in abrindo2:
                    print msmwebsite, 'up'

                else:
                    pass

        else:
            pass
```

It's working but for some reason, some websites I got this error:

```
if abrindo.code == 200:
NameError: name 'abrindo' is not defined
```

How to fix it?
.......................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `pass` with `continue`. And at least do some error logging, as you silently skip erroneous links.

In case your request resulted in an `URLError`, no variable `abrindo` is defined, hence your error.

Comment: I did it, funny that's in a website that I tested, exists one of "palavras" words but isn't printed '-'.

Comment: Now I fixed it, was a mistake of mine. Thanks Alko :)!

Answer (score 2):

`abrindo` is created only in the `try` block. It will not be available if the `catch` block is executed. To fix this, move the block of code starting with

```
if abrindo.code == 200:
```

inside the `try` block. One more suggestion, if you are not doing anything in the `else` part, instead of explicitly writing that with `pass`, simply remove them.

Comment: Moving lots of code inside a `try` block isn't recommended, because it can mask bugs (even if it won't with this exact code, it *can* in general, including as the code evolves). Instead, it could be put in an `else:` block aligned with the `try` (which is executed if and only iff no `except` blocks are), or by (as another answer suggests) changing the `except: pass` to `except: continue`.